# How does compareTo method of Comparable class work for objects

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparable

Say I had a Movie class with the following instance variables:

```
private String myTitle; // title of Bond film
private String myBondActor; // name of actor who portrayed James Bond
private int myYear; // year film was released
private double myFilmRating;// from all-reviews.com
private int myLengthHours; // hours (truncated) portion of film length
private int myLengthMinutes;// minutes beyond truncated hours
```

and I had an `ArrayList` of `Movie` objects, and I used a bubble sort algorithm to sort the `ArrayList`:

```
public void bubbleSort(ArrayList<Movie> list) {
for (int outer = 0; outer < list.size() - 1; outer++) {
    for (int inner = 0; inner < list.size() - outer - 1; inner++) {
        if (list.get(inner).compareTo(list.get(inner + 1)) > 0) {
            Movie temp = list.get(inner);
            list.set(inner, list.get(inner + 1));
            list.set(inner + 1, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

How is the `ArrayList` being sorted?

Answer (score 3):

See when you do int x= 5,y=10 and we can now compare them like `x<y, we can compare two variables, but how do we compare two objects ??`

**We compare objects by compareTo()**, Your Movie class must implement **Comparable** interface in order to compare its objects with one another.

You have to provide implementation to compareTo() method, **this criteria will decide which object is greater than the other.**

For Example, Let us say a movie should be sorted(compared) based on int myYear(year of release) of film  so implementation will be

```
public int compareTo(Movie other)
{
   return this.myYear - other.getMyYear();
}
```

Now we create two objects m1 and m2 of type Movie where m1.myYear=2000 and m2.myYear=2001

when we do `m1.compareTo(m2);`

- we get 2000 - 2001 = -1...  A Negative number, that means m1 < m2.
- If we get a positive number then m1 > m2
- if we get a zero then m1 ==m2

*Here I decide which Movie object is greater than the other based on myYear* , you may decided on something else maybe more condtions.
**Whatever the condition may be, remember the number you return +ve , -ve or a 0 (Zero) will decide which object is greater than the other.**

Comment: documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 1):

You would have to implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and the `compareTo()` method *yourself*, such that you would compare using your object attributes (e.g. title, year etc.)

> int compareTo(T o)
>
> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Note the various caveats relating to associativity etc.

I presume you're writing the sort yourself, as an exercise. You can use `Collections.sort()`, which implements QuickSort, and this method allows an optional [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) object, which allows you to implement different comparisons (e.g. you could sort by name, by actor name, by release date etc. by substituting in different comparators)

Answer (score 0):

Implement `Comparable` interface:

```
class Movie implements Comparable 
{
    private String myTitle; 
    private String myBondActor; 
    private int myYear; 
    private double myFilmRating;
    private int myLengthHours; 
    private int myLengthMinutes;

    // Override CompareTo Method
    public int compareTo ( Movie m )
    {
         // Here comparison logic
    }
}
```

Now just call the method like this:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```